# Broken CSS links in Play 2.5 Project

Tags: java, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, playframework

I have a Java Play 2.5 project with the following directory structure:

- project-dir

  - app
  - assets

    - images
    - javascripts
    - stylesheets
  - models
  - views
  - controllers
  - public

    - images
    - javascripts
    - stylesheets
  - target

This is more or less taken directly from [anatomy of a Play project](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Anatomy).

However, I am unable to link the assets (CSS and images) from the `public` directory to `main.scala.html`.

We have the following route in the `routes` file:

```
GET  /assets/*file  controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

And we link the assets like so in `main.scala.html`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Assets.at("stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css")">
```

This gives a compilation error: not enough arguments for method at

It seems that the compiler does not see that we declared the first argument to method at to be fixed (`path="/public"` in the `routes` file).

Based on [my research in the Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AssetsOverview), this error happens when multiple routes are declared that fix the `path` parameter, but this is definitely not the case for me. I have only one single route that invokes the Assets controller.

If I explicitly call at with both parameters like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Assets.at("/public", "stylesheets/style.css")">
```

Then the project runs successfully, but when I load the homepage in the browser, none of my CSS is present. Has anyone run in to a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a fix by setting my routes like so:

```
GET  /assets/*file  controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

and calling assets like so:

```
<img src="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/home_page.jpg")" class="img-responsive" alt="My Image">
```

Source: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AssetsOverview#reverse-routing-and-fingerprinting-for-public-assets